# Replacing a expression with a return statement in TypeScript transformer results in "Debug Failure. Unhandled SyntaxKind: ReturnStatement"

Tags: typescript, typescript-compiler-api

I'm trying to write a TypesScript transformer to transform a specific function call to a return statement using the following transformer.

```js
export default function transformer(program: ts.Program, config?: PluginConfig): ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> {
  const transformerFactory: ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> = context => {
    return sourceFile => {
      const visitor = (node: ts.Node): ts.Node => {
        if (ts.isCallExpression(node) && node.expression.getText(sourceFile).indexOf("someFunction") != -1) {
          const factory = context.factory;
          if (node.arguments.length != 2) {
            throw new Error("The argument list is not of size 2");
          }
          
          return factory.createReturnStatement(factory.createStringLiteral("1"));
        }
        return ts.visitEachChild(node, visitor, context);
      };

      return ts.visitNode(sourceFile, visitor);
    };
  };
  return transformerFactory;
}
```

When I run the transformer with ttypescript, I get `Debug Failure. Unhandled SyntaxKind: ReturnStatement`.
After some digging, I find that the problem is that tsc thinks the new node(return statement) is still an expression(EmitHint == 1).
Is it possible to replace a expression with a statement inside a TypeScript transformer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging, I find that the call expression is wrapping inside a `ExpressionStatement`. As the name suggests, a `ExpressionStatement` is a statement can be replaced by a return statement.
The final code:

```js
export default function transformer(program: ts.Program, config?: PluginConfig): ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> {
  const transformerFactory: ts.TransformerFactory<ts.SourceFile> = context => {
    return sourceFile => {
      const visitor = (node: ts.Node): ts.Node => {
        if (ts.isExpressionStatement(node) && ts.isCallExpression(node.expression) && node.expression.getText(sourceFile).indexOf("someFunction") != -1) {
          const factory = context.factory;
          if (node.expression.arguments.length != 2) {
            throw new Error("The argument list is not of size 2");
          }
          
          return factory.createReturnStatement(factory.createStringLiteral("1"));
        }
        return ts.visitEachChild(node, visitor, context);
      };

      return ts.visitNode(sourceFile, visitor);
    };
  };
  return transformerFactory;
}
```